# Document Being Accessed by Multiple Users

Tags: microsoft-excel, network-shares

When I am on my home network, I have an Excel spreadsheet that lists all the music I have added to our network library. This document is accessible by all members and needs to remain that way as we all access it multiple times a week. Unfortunately, two users can access the document and make changes. Of course who ever finishes first will end up losing their changed data as when the second saves the file, it overwrites the existing. I have no other option but to keep this file accessible to all users and not split it up.

Is there a a program or any way to configure the file to inform me that someone is currently viewing the document and making changes? I need a way for others to know that it is being accessed and edited by a particular person. Any ideas?

Comment: I actually have a domain server. So how would I make this work on the domain?

Comment: I'm wrong, I think mnmnc is correct, are you using office 2010? Earlier versions of office will not allow more than 1 user to open a document in write mode, but this changed with office 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use '[share workbook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-shared-workbooks-HP005262294.aspx)' option in Excel. It is located on the Review tab. It has option to allow/disallow changes made by other users at the same time. It has function of workbook merging. 
It also keeps the track of changes history so you will be able to return to previously saved version. It will ask users if they want to save in case conflict will be detected.

It also provides auto save option every X minutes.

Anyone who will open this file will be able to see if someone else is already using this document as there is a box:

[image: who has this workbook open now]

Showing who already opened the file. I have removed my username but it is normally showing there in the place of black rectangle.

Check if this is what you are looking for.